# How to export schema only for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I have a very big PostgresSQL database. I would like to dump the schema only. Running

```
pg_dump -s myschema -f /dump.sql
```

runs forever, so I suppose it is exporting the data as well. How can I dump the schema only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-s` takes no parameter, you need to use `-n` or `--schema` to select the schema you want to dump:

```
pg_dump -s -n myschema -d mydatabase -f /dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this avoid dumping the data?

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes it will

Comment: It's still running... Sorry for the slow reply.